# XAMARIN How to use the event handler of a button that has been created by another button

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So i've made a program that has an "Add to favourite" button (a favourite color) so i select a color and when i click the "Add" button it goes to the event handler (pressed) and creates a new button with this code :

```
        Frame frame;
        private void OnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
               parent.Children.Add(frame = new Frame
                {
                    BorderColor = Color.Black,
                    Padding = new Thickness(5),
                    Content = new StackLayout
                    {
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        Children =
                        {
                            new Button
                            {
                                Text="btn",

                            },
                            new Label
                            {
                                Text ="sample text", FontSize=Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
                                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
         }
```

the thing is i want to detect if those created buttons are pressed too so i can code in their own eventHandler.

Btw, it isn't about the colors (it's just to illustrate the thing) but more about the "Add to favourite" system.

Thanks in advance :))

Comment: I think you should create the button `var newButton = new Button{...}`, attach an event handler to it `newButton.OnClick+=...` and then add it `Children =  newButton, new Label...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set he eventHandler is OK.

```
........your code
new Button
  {
      Text="btn",

  }
......
```

it should changed to:

```
var button=new Button{Text="btn"};
button.Click=OnAdd;
```

and then make this `button` to your **frame**.

Comment: okay i tried it and yeah i don't know why i didn't think about that that way, thanks

Comment: @rems happy coding

Answer (score 1):

So yeah i basically made something like this and it just works :)

```
        private void OnAdd(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btnFav = new Button { Text = "btn"};
            btnFav.Clicked += ONbtnFav;

                parent.Children.Add(frame = new Frame
                {
                    BorderColor = Color.Black,
                    Padding = new Thickness(5),
                    Content = new StackLayout
                    {
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        Children =
                        {
                            btnFav,
                            new Label
                            {
                                Text ="sample text", FontSize=Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
                                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
         }
```